# Upper Bound for n-th derivative of a rational function.

Tags: calculus

Show that for all $x∈R$, $$\left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right|≤n!$$

We are given the hint to split $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ into  $\frac{1}{2(1+ix)}+\frac{1}{2(1-ix)}$. I have attempted to do so, but have no idea how to continue from the following: $$\frac{n!}{2}\frac{(x-i)^n+(i-x)^n}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. That doesn't look like the correct expression for the $n$th derivative.

Comment: You can get properly sized norm bars (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki, thank you I'll fix that now.

Comment: @J.G., yeah my bad. I think I input it slightly wrong. I believe it should be correct now. I'm still stuck on showing how that's less than n!...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than combining everything into a single term, leave it separated. Then you'll have something like

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \frac{n!}{2} \left( \frac{(-i)^n}{(1 + ix)^{n + 1}} + \frac{i^n}{(1 - ix)^{n + 1}} \right)$$

Then if you apply the triangle inequality, you will get

$$\begin{eqnarray} \left| \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{1}{1 + x^2} \right| & = & \left| \frac{n!}{2} \left( \frac{(-i)^n}{(1 + ix)^{n + 1}} + \frac{i^n}{(1 - ix)^{n + 1}} \right) \right| \\
& \leq & \frac{n!}{2} \left(\left| \frac{(-i)^n}{(1 + ix)^{n + 1}} \right| + \left| \frac{i^n}{(1 - ix)^{n + 1}} \right| \right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Then if you can prove that both terms are bounded by 1, you're done.